# What kind of palm/plant is this?

Tags: identification, palm

[image: New Plant]

What is this? I feel like it was named incorrectly when I bought it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a palm but a Yucca. The leaves are curled up a bit, I think it needs some water or it could also be a sign of overwatering (hard to tell from a picture, feel the soil with fingers).